# Graph Isomorphism Algorithm of Vertex Transitive Graphs and other.

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

What are the best known Graph-Isomorphism algorithms for  below graph classes-

1.vertex-transitive,  2. edge-transitive,  3.arc-transitive (or symmetric) 4.distance-transitive.

Provide run-times/time complexity of algorithm, if possible.

*Also, If a graph has large number of automorphisms like above graphs, is it helpful to determine isomorphism? Is there any such relationship  in current literature ?*

Comment: Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated. You can re-ask it (but give a link to this question if you do).

Answer (score 1):

Graph Isomorphism  of *Vertex Transistive Graphs* is ***GI Complete***(Graph-Isomorphism Complete) .

**Vertex-transitivity test can be done by testing graph isomorphism $n−1$ times:**  Make two copies $G$ and $G'$ of your graph,
with special anchors (like paths of length $n+1$) at $u \in V(G)$ and $v \in V(G')$. There is an isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ if and only if the original graph has an automorphism mapping $u$ to $v$.
Thus you can test vertex-tansitivity by fixing a vertex $x$,
and checking that there are automorphisms mapping $x$ to all the other vertices. *So,  if vertex-transitivity test can be done in polynomial time, then so is isomorphism test for vertex-transitive graphs (there exists a polynomial time reduction).*
This is because two vertex-transitive graphs are isomorphic if and only if their disjoint union is vertex-transitive, thus computational complexity of graph isomorphism for vertex-transitive graphs  lies in the same class of graph isomorphism .

See a related paper by Jajcay, Malnič, Marušič [1] , it says -

> For a given finite graph $\Gamma$,
>   it is decidedly hard to determine whether $\Gamma$ is vertex-transitive,
>   and the ultimate answer comes usually only after a substantial part of
>   the full automorphism group of $\Gamma$ has been determined.

So, saying a graph is vertex transitive gives no extra information, benefits to test isomorphism.  One has to find out the automorphism set of the *Vertex Transistive Graph* . Determining  a generating set for automorphism group of a given graph is  ***GI Complete*** (Due to **Rudi Mathon** [2]), it means that the determining the a generating set for automorphism group of a given graph is  equal to solving graph isomorphism problem .

Same argument could be used to  edge-transitive, arc-transitive (or symmetric) , distance-transitive graph.

**Addition:**

  1.

> Thank you very much for your edit. Your reduction from VT to Iso is
>   elegant and can be improved to a many-one reduction: simply ask for
>   graph isomorphism,   once, of the disjoint union of all the copies.
>   Next, you provide a reduction from VTIso (vertex transitive graph
>   isomorphism) to VT, so we now know that $VTIso \leq VT \leq Iso$. Does
>   the reverse, $Iso \leq VTIso$, hold? I tried finding a reduction for
>   $Iso\leq VTIso$ and for $VT\leq Aut$, but failed.

- from comment of Lieuwe Vinkhuijzen .

---

1. Jajcay, Malnič, Marušič. On the number of closed walks in vertex-transitive graphs. Discrete Math. 307 (2007) 484-493. [[doi:10.1016/j.disc.2005.09.039](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2005.09.039)][JMM07]
2. [Mathon, Rudolf (1979), "A note on the graph isomorphism counting problem", Information Processing Letters, 8 (3): 131–132, doi:10.1016/0020-0190(79)90004-8](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019079900048)

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the claim that generating a graph's automorphism group is equivalent to solving graph isomorphism in the case where both graphs are known to be vertex transitive? I cannot find Mathon's result on Google scholar, and even if I could, the fact that in general finding the automorphism group is GI Complete does not mean that this is also true for the case of vertex-transitive graphs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. Your reduction from VT to Iso is elegant and can be improved to a many-one reduction: simply ask for graph isomorphism, once, of the disjoint union of all the copies. Next, you provide a reduction from VTIso (vertex transitive graph isomorphism) to VT, so we now know that $VTIso \leq VT \leq Iso$. Does the reverse, $Iso \leq VTIso$, hold? This is what we are looking for when we ask whether VTIso is GI-Complete. I tried finding a reduction for $Iso\leq VTIso$ and for $VT\leq Aut$, but failed.

Comment: You appended my comment to your answer, but did not answer the question whether graph isomorphism reduces to graph isomorphism to vertex-transitive graphs. Also, this question and answer look much more at home at cs.stackexchange or cstheory.stackexchange, but I don't have the power to migrate it.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen , I have asked it on CST ME : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36878/graph-isomorphism-algorithm-of-vertex-transistive-graphs-and-other